# getFileTime always return 01/01/1601

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, date, time, msdn

```
  HANDLE f = CreateFile(filepath,GENERIC_ALL,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
          FILETIME create, access, write;

          GetFileTime(f,&create,&access,&write);
          std::cout << "debug " << std::endl;
          SYSTEMTIME s;
          FileTimeToSystemTime(&create,&s);
          displayTime(s);
```

In this code, i'm trying to get a file and display its create/last access/ last modified time. So I get a FILETIME and i convert it into a SYSTEMTIME and I display it.

Problem, all the file in the repertory have the same date : 01/01/1601.
I know that in the file system, the "timestamp" is calculated from 01/01/1601 but I don't understand what the file I have created today for my test are from this date.

Comment: The complete lack of error checking ensures that, if this goes wrong, that you never know why.  Do **not** ignore the return value of winapi functions, especially for the kind of functions that fail frequently.  Like anything related to the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter, OPEN_EXISTING, means that only an existing file is opened. It does not create a file, which explains why the modified time is unitialised.

Use CREATE_ALWAYS or similar instead.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My file are created BEFORE the program start, that is why I though I have to use OPEN_EXISTING. Thank you